# How to retrieve multiple check box value using explode?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have several check boxes and when the multiple check box is clicked & form is submitted it goes in the db search for the corresponding result but it is giving me notice :

```
Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\enoticeboard\home.php on line 68
```

this error is 3 times.

how I successfully retrieve it?
my code is:

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(!$user->is_loggedin())
{
   $user->redirect('index.php');
}
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id");
$stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));
$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>



 <!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>welcome -
        <?php print($userRow[ 'user_email']); ?>
    </title>
    <style>
        .left {
            margin-left: 20px;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="header">
        <div class="left">
            <label><a>Welcome : <?php print($userRow['user_name']); ?></a> </label>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <label><a href="logout.php?logout=true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i> logout</a>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <h1>Notice Board</h1>
        <div class="left">
            <h4>Select Hostel,Branch,Year</h4>
            <form action="home.php" method="POST">
                <label>Hostel</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="hostel[]" value="K.P-1">K.P-1</input>
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="hostel[]" value="K.P-2">K.P-2</input>
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="hostel[]" value="K.P-3">K.P-3</input>
                <br/>
                <label>Branch</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="branch[]" value="CSE">CSE</input>
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="branch[]" value="I.T">I.T</input>
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="branch[]" value="CIVIL">CIVIL</input>
                <br/>
                <label>YEAR</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="year[]" value="2011">2011</input>
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="year[]" value="2012">2012</input>
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="year[]" value="2013">2013</input>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="See Notices" />
            </form>
        </div>
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['hostel']) && isset($_POST['branch']) && isset($_POST['year']))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['hostel']) && !empty($_POST['branch']) &&  !empty($_POST['year']))
{
            $arrayName = $_POST['hostel'];
            $arrayName2 = $_POST['branch'];
            $arrayName3 = $_POST['year'];
            $hostel=explode(",",$arrayName);
            $branch=explode(",",$arrayName2);
            $year=explode(",",$arrayName3);
            $stmt2=$DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM doc WHERE hostel=:hostel AND branch=:branch AND year=:year");
            $stmt2->execute(array(':hostel'=>$hostel,':branch'=>$branch,':year'=>$year));
            $userRow2=$stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
             ?>
            <div class="middle">
                <?php
                if($userRow2 > 0){
                        foreach($userRow2['doc'] as $value2){
                        print_r($value2['doc']);
                        echo 'hi';
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "No records.";
            }
                ?>
                </div>
                <?php

        }
        else {
            echo "No Notice Found.";
        }
}
else {
    echo "Please fill in all fields.";
 }
 ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`foreach` is your friend](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0):

[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function splits string into array.

[implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function converts array into string.

So, it requires string as second parameter.

Your checkbox `branch[]` is already getting posted as array.

`$_POST['branch']` is an array.

You do not need to explode() the checkbox array.

I think you need to combine array into a string.

So, use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Just use:

```
$arrayName2 = $_POST['branch'];
$branch=implode(",",$arrayName2);
```

Instead of

```
$arrayName2 = $_POST['branch'];
$branch=explode(",",$arrayName2);
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I got rid of the error but now it is showing me new error that is:Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\enoticeboard\home.php on line 78

Comment: `$userRow2['doc']` is not getting value. You should add a condition: `if (! empty($userRow2['doc'])) {...`

Answer (score 0):

The warning is clear [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) requires parameter 2 be string, but you are passing array there. If you want to join array element with comma then you should use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) as below :

```
$hostel=implode(",",$arrayName);
$branch=implode(",",$arrayName2);
$year=implode(",",$arrayName3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    echo "<pre>"; 
    print_r($_POST);
    $checked = implode(',', $_POST['checkbox']); 
    echo $checked;
}
```